# Load bootstrap modal from a Menu Item (executeJavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am trying to load a Bootstrap Modal from a Electron menuItem using `executeJavaScript`methood. Unfortunately I keep getting a error that `executeJavaScript is not a function` and/or `webContents is not a function`.

Here's the code of the menu item from app.js:

```
role: 'help',
submenu: [
{
        label: 'Test preferences',
        click: (event) => {
          const { executeJavaScript } = require('electron')
executeJavaScript('$("#ComformationNOW").modal("show")', true)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // Will be the JSON object from the fetch call
  })
}
]
```

here's also a sample from Electron app.js as well.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, MenuItem, webContents} = require('electron')
let mainWindow;


function mainWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  
  let contents = mainWindow.webContents
console.log(contents)
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

Comment: can you call it through the browser window reference? for e.x if the browser window variable is "win" then try win.webContents.executeJavaScript

Comment: I tried that and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of undefined`.

Comment: where do you create the instance of BrowserWindow? and what is the name of the variable that holds that instance?

Comment: well I have updated the question with another sample of the first thing that went into app.js (as it cannot fit into the comments)

Comment: from this code I do not see the variable "let win;" to be initiated anywhere (so its null). The variable that holds the BrowserWindow is "mainWindow" but its only scoped inside the function createWindow so its not accessible outside the createWindow function. So if i understand correctly you can do the following changes. Rename "let win" to "let mainWindow", change "const mainWindow" to just "mainWindow" (remove the const) and also replace the win.webContents with mainWindow.webContents  and on your click handler call the executeJavaScript as mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript

Comment: I did that........unexpected token '{', has to do with `mainWindow () { CODE GOES HERE }`

Comment: can you post your updated code?. because from what you wrote its like you changed the name of the function "createWindow"

Comment: it's edited just now

Comment: Please correct "mainWindow()" to "function createWindow()" and below that correct "const mainWindow" to "mainWindow" (remove the const)

Comment: please update code after every change in order to confirm everything is done correctly

Comment: I updated it, still `SyntaxError: Identifier 'mainWindow' has already been declared`.

Comment: Please  correct "function mainWindow()" to "function createWindow()" .